# Dart/Polymer loading screen?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I want to give users some visual feedback during load in.  I'm wondering if there is a way to hook into the polymer loading/binding phase so that a loading screen can be shown to the user?  Silverlight has something like this where you can show a customizable progress bar while it is downloading.

If there is a way, how is it done with Dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example (JS) shows how to do a splash screen using native HTML Imports, without Polymer: http://jsbin.com/wozorebo/4/quiet

It also shows how to use the CSS [`:unresolved` pseudo-class](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#fouc-prevention).

With Polymer, you can listen for the [`polymer-ready` event](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready) to do something similar. Apply a class on the body element when that event fires.

Comment: I'm not sure the with-polymer example would work with Dart, considering how the bootstrap works (it may, not sure).  But the non-polymer example will do just fine.  Thanks!